# 'testing-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release

Tags: debian, apt

I've installed Debian bullseye on an older machine to play around with. I just updated all repos to testing with the guide from [DebianTesting](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting).

> 1. Edit your apt sources, changing 'stable' (or bullseye, the current codename for stable) to 'testing' (or bookworm, the current code name for the next stable release).
> 2. Remove, disable or comment out your stable security updates apt sources (anything with security.debian.org in it).
> 3. Remove, disable or comment out any other stable-specific apt sources, like *-backports or *-updates.
> 4. Verify that your installation is not fixed to a specific release in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00default-release

It states I should remove all stable-specific sources, but as I generally don't follow orders, I replaced bullseye-updates and bullseye-backports with the appropriate testing tag. And see: `apt update` doesn't even complain. I double checked and there is indeed a testing-backports folder in [remote repository](https://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-backports/).

But after running `apt upgrade -s -t testing-backports` to see what packages have newer version in this repo, it failes with the above mentioned error message:

```
E: The value 'testing-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

I verified that the command works on another Debian system with `stable-backports`.

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-backports main
```

So is it there indeed no repo for `testing-backports`, because the release file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testing-backports` is empty (see all the 0-length `Packages` files in [`Release`](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-backports/Release)), which is why it can’t be used here.

The backports repositories are used to provide packages from `testing` rebuilt for stable suites, so `testing-backports` has no purpose.

Note that using a backports repository as the default release (even temporarily using `-t`) with operations which touch the whole distribution (`apt upgrade` etc.) is a bad idea since the backports repository doesn’t host a consistent distribution.

Comment: That's why I used the -s flag

Comment: Yes, and that’s fine — I’ve seen more than a few users run `apt -t foo-backports upgrade` and just wanted to make sure that readers in general were aware of the dangers.